# for loop finding the prime numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code to print the sum of all the prime numbers less than 2 million. This loop is never ending. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? It seems to work with smaller numbers though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        long result = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<2000000; i++) {
            if(isPrime(i)) {
                result+= i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    boolean result = false;

    for(long i=2; i<(long)Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if(n%i == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        else result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please post isPrime code

Comment: My guess is that your isPrime takes longer and longer. You could verify that by adding a debug output every time isPrimer results in true. Also, should result start at 1?

Comment: The current code has a bug.  If a number is the product of two prime numbers, it will be incorrectly identified as prime.  If I were writing the code I would have `i<=(long)Math.sqrt(n)+1` (because I don't know how rounding works - does `(long)Math.sqrt(25)` become `(long)4.99999` become `4`? - and I would prefer a little inefficiency over incorrect results).  Either that or look up how java does rounding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `isPrime` you are only testing division by 2:

```
private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    boolean result = false;

    for(long i=1; i<n/2; i++) {
        if(n%2 == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        else result = true;
    }
    return result;

}
```

it should be division by every `i` and starting from 2:

```
for(long i=2; i<n/2; i++) {
    if(n%i == 0) {
      ...
```

Practically in your current version an odd number `n` will keep dividing by 2 up to `n/2` instead of stopping much sooner. Consider n = 21. You are dividing by 2 from 1 to 10, instead of dividing by 3 at the 3rd step and exiting.

It not only gives incorrect results, but also takes much longer than needed to reach a `return` statement.

**Edit**: For faster results check out this sieve of Erathostenes method:

```
public static long sumOfPrimes(int n) {

    long sum = 0;

    boolean[] sieve = new boolean[n];
    for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if(!sieve[i]) {
            for(int j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(!sieve[i]) {             
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**Edit #2**: Found some bugs with your new version. Here's the corrected one:

```
private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    boolean result = false;

    if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;

    for (long i = 2; i <= (long) Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        } else
            result = true;
    }

    System.out.println(n + " " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: but for that i might need to keep an array of all the prime numbers less than 'n' to avoid it. I think it's much lengthier.

Comment: @Bohemian: Right, the division by 1. Thanks.

Comment: @nick-s: No, you don't. This is just the corrected version of your initial `isPrime` method. No need to change anything in your overall algorithm. Just plug it in and test.

Comment: guys, i have made the changes but still it keeps on looping. i have posted the code in the original question. can you see what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @nick-s: It could be that it's just too slow. Have you tried to put a `println` inside the `isPrime` method to check if it's detecting the primes correctly?

Comment: @Tudor I just found out that if the range is 6 digits i.e., below 1 million, the loop works fine and gives me the right answer, but when I type in 1 million which is 7 digits, the loop runs indefinitely.

Comment: @nick-s: Check my edits to the answer. First one is a very fast method to solve the problem. Second one is a correction of your initial method which had some bugs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12107/discussion-between-nick-s-and-tudor)

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in `isPrime()`

The test should be:

```
if(n%i == 0) { ...
```

and you need to start counting at `2`, not `1`, because every number has a remainder of zero when divided by `1`!

Also, no need to go past `Math.sqrt(n)`.

You should change it to this:

```
private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    long max = (long)Math.sqrt(n);
    for (long i = 2; i < max; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

FYI, with this change, I tested the program on my PC and it completed in under 1 second, giving the result of `143064094810`

Comment: why is it that i don't need to go past **Math.sqrt(n)**??

Comment: Because you are trying to find `a * b == n` and `Math.sqrt(n) * Math.sqrt(n) == n`, so any number larger than `Math.sqrt(n)` for `a`  you will already have tried on the way up as `b`.

Answer (score 0):

A naive `isPrime` function must calculate all the primes up to `i` (or at least up to `sqrt(i)`) each time it runs. Make sure your isPrime function caches its results!

Answer (score 0):

### Tested and bug free Prime check function

```
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return false;

    for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a complete program of Prime using JOptionPane, i.e. Java GUI**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChkPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter any number: ","Input...", 3);

        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(str);


            if (num == 1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your inputed no. " + num + " is not prime.","Error!", 0);

            for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
                if(num % i == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your inputed no. " + num + " is not prime.","Error!", 0);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your inputed no. " + num + " is prime.","Yeh! Got it!", 1);
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input numbers...","Error!", 0);
            main(null);
        }
    }
}
```