# How to make an infinite for loop (for(;;)) not crash?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm new to JS, so most of my code hasn't worked. I've made a program to find out every prime number, but every time I use it, it crashes. Is there any way to make this code not crash upon running?

```
var i = 0;

for (;;) {
    if (i % 2 === 0 || i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0) {
        i++;
    }
    else {
        return i;
        i++;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct algorithm for prime numbers. `121` for example in your code is seen as prime number

Comment: `return` outside of a function?

Comment: `i++` after `return` statement does not make sense

Comment: This is wrong in so many different ways. Apart from the algorithm itself, this not how you use `return` keyword

Comment: `return` should be inside a function scope! I assume you are running your code in the global scope and that is throwing an error!

Comment: I get the impression @Levent has forgotten to include the `function() {}` wrap otherwise the loop will just not work (as opposed to infinite recursion). Despite this, it's still the wrong algorithm anyway!

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880669/for-loop-finding-the-prime-numbers

Comment: Aside from all of my other errors, I could've sworn that I replaced return with console.log.

Comment: please add the algorithm, you use. actually it stops on `1`, if the `return` statement is replaced by a `break`, which exits `for` and `do`/`while` loops (and `switch`'s `case` as well).

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to use a single timer. Using setInterval, you can achieve what you want as follows:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    primes();
}
function primes() {
    var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (i % 2 === 0 || i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0) {
            i++;
        } else {
            console.log(i);
            i++;
        }
    }, 1000); // repeat forever, new value every 1 second
}
```

This will print the values to the console once a match is found (It does a check every second). But you can adjust this on the second parameter of the setInterval function.

If you want the results on the actual page, you can replace the console.log() with document.createTextNode().

Also, i have not checked this or know if the algorithm is right. Just adapted from your code.

Answer (score 0):

List of fixes:

- You manually update `i` and use a blank for loop instead of using the for loop normally, but having the middle condition always return true (a `while` loop could be used here also, but would still require manually updating `i`) as you don't plan on stopping. However, you can actually just put the whole thing in a timer instead of a loop, like @Leonel Atencio did.
- You use `return` outside of a function, and if you did put this code inside of a function, it would just return the first prime number every time, so it would always return `1`.
- The formula is incorrect, only checking for some examples of primes; As @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai said, 121 would be considered prime, even though it is 11x11.

Fixed:

```js
var primes = [];
var i = 1; //Start at 2; since "i" is incremented at the start of the function, this won't start it at 1, which would cause problems (the array would only have 1 in it, since all other whole numebrs are divisible by one)
setInterval(primeFunc,100);
function primeFunc(){
    i++; //Increment current number
    isPrime=true; //Assume prime
    for(var j=0;j<primes.length;j++){ //Rule out non-primes with the power of modulo
        if(i%primes[j]==0) { //If the current number can be divided (is divisible) by any previous prime...
            //...then it's not a prime, so cancel any further chacks and move on
            isPrime=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime){
        //The current number is not divisible by any other primes, so it is itself a prime; if it was divisible, isPrime would be set to false by our loop above
        primes.push(i);
        output.innerHTML=primes;
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```